# How to wrap flex block with absolute position limited by height?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/q14nuebw/5/

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 10px;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 90px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">111</div>
  <div class="item">222</div>
  <div class="item">333</div>
  <div class="item">444</div>
</div>
```

`container` has `position:absolute` and `flex-wrap: wrap`. If height is limited, blocks shift to left, but parent block doesn't wrap all blocks, just first column.

Use `width: 100%` in this case is not a solution.
Is it possible with flex blocks to solve this?

Comment: What do you mean "parent block doesn't wrap all blocks, just first column"? I only see one column of "items". Are you asking why the container doesn't expand in width to accommodate the second column of data?

Comment: It cant wrap because you have max-height set there.